# Can't import more then one blend shape into Unity using Blender

Tags: export, unity, shape-keys

I save the object with many blend shape keys. They work in blender, but I can't see them in Unity on the Skinned Mesh Renderer

I see only if I had only one key on blend shape in Blender.

Comment: Aha! I had an extra Collision modifier left on the one that didn't go through. Ty so much!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

apply all of your modifiers before importing to Unity

Your shape keys must be set to 0 influence in blender before being imported.

export from blender as an .fbx file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this works. Modifiers get applied automatically when exporting, so this may break the shape keys during the export process.

If you apply the modifiers in Blender (excluding the armature modifier), you can also import the .blend directly into Unity.